# Views Bootstrap (Carousel) Not Working

Tags: views, javascript

I've installed the Views Bootstrap module primarily so that I can easily create the same carousels that the Bootstrap/non Drupal parts of our site use. I would prefer to use Views Bootstrap or else I will have to use a different carousel module and try to style it so it looks the same.

I have for images in my result set. All I am getting right now is a page with one number for each image like this:

1.
2.
3.
4.

Below this I get the images, left aligned, one per row.

In the view settings I am using Bootstrap Carousel for Format and Bootstrap Carousel for Show. I get this same result whether I am using this view as a block or as a page. I don't know if it matters but I am using the Omega 3 theme.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To use [Views Bootstrap](https://drupal.org/project/views_bootstrap) module you need to have theme that based on [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). If your theme is not based on it, you may take a look to similar modules, such as [Nivo slider](https://drupal.org/project/nivo_slider)

Answer (score 1):

That's how it appears in the view but, if you place your view in a panel or in a region you'll see the bootstrap carousel working like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue where my Slideshow images were listed in an order, instead of functioning as a slideshow. Initially I though it was the problem of Jquery.

But it was not basically I read through the documentation found that for my version of Drupal and Bootstrap which is Drupal 8 and Bootstrap 3 I am suppose to install 8.x-3.x version of Views_Bootstrap

Walla! All of sudden my slide show started to work again.